# Write Lecture Notes in VS Code

Tags: vscode, code-snippets

I would (like many before me) like to take my lecture notes using LaTeX. As writing pure LaTeX-code is very time consuming and not nearly as fast as handwriting, I can only really consider switching to LaTeX if I can use snippets and anything else that makes notetaking faster.
I have discovered [this](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/) post on how to get faster using vim, but at this point I don't really want to learn vim anymore. I know it is very hyped, and probably worth learning, but I have so much else do learn already that I don't know if I will ever find the time. At the moment I am very happy with VS Code (or really VSCodium) for all developing, scripting and stuff that I do, and as I can perfectly do just about everything within this one editor, I would very much like to keep it.
Saying this, has anyone an idea or a hint for me on how to set up something like the blog post describes using VS Code? That would be very appreciated.

Comment: Vim-editor isn‘t everybody’s cup of tea (it‘s simple and fast, but I always forget the commands) … Instead you can use any other editor, like notepad, notepad++, emacs and what have you. If you‘ll compile later, that‘s all you need.

Comment: I have the same problem that I cannot remember commands, thats why I would like to use VSCode. But the article relies very much on vim as it explains many things using explicit features/plugins for vim. That is where my question is pointed at, I would like to use such features in VSCode.

Comment: Ok :) // Try https://www.google.com/search?q=vim+cheat+sheet and select a linlk or one of the images shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the LaTeX Workshop extension installed (which I recommend) then many command completions are already installed which should speed up your input considerably. But you can add custom snippets to your editor environment to add more complex bits of markup.

To do this, go to Settings -> Configure User Snippets and then choose LaTeX as your language.

Snippets in VSCode have the following structure:

```
"Snippet Name": {
    "prefix": "...",
    "body": [ ... ],
    "description": "..."
}
```

The prefix is the element you want type to insert the snippet. The body is an array object containing the code you want to insert. Each element of the array is a line. Within the body you can use `$1`, `$2` etc. to mark insertion points. These will be traversed sequentially using the Tab key when the snippet is inserted.

For more details see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

### Example

I use the `gb4e` package extensively, so here's an example of a snippet that inserts a block of code corresponding to a linguistic example.   Note that backslashes need to be doubled.

The snippet is the following:

```
"Insert Example":{
        "prefix": "exe",
        "body": [
            "\\begin{exe}",
            "   \\ex\\label{$1}",
            "   \\begin{xlist}",
            "       \\ex{$2}",
            "   \\end{xlist}",
            "\\end{exe}"
        ],
        "description": "gb4e example"
    }
```

When I type `exe` in the editor it gives me a selection to choose:

[image: snippet selection]

I then insert the snippet, and the following code is added to my document.

```
\begin{exe}
    \ex\label{}
    \begin{xlist}
        \ex{}
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}
```

The cursor is placed inside the `\label{}` braces, so that I can enter a label for the example. If I then hit the Tab key the cursor will move to inside the `\ex{}` braces so that I can insert the first example.

Comment: First, thank you for your detailed answer. I already knew about snippets within VSCode, they just never worked the way I wanted them to, maybe I really just need to define all my own ones. Do you know if anyone already has ported the vim snippets presented in the article to VSCode? Next up would be the use of sympy and spelling corrections, is there an equivalent as well? Or the replacement of formulas while a line isn't focussed with readable math unicode?

Comment: @DarkDiamond well I can't comment on what works for you, nor do I know whether the particular set of VIM snippets has been ported. You might want to look on GitHub for such things, see e.g. https://github.com/JeffersonQin/VSCode-LaTeX-Snippets but I'm sure there are others. The same goes for spelling. I don't use VSCode that much for LaTeX personally, nor do I use much math, so this isn't a priority for me.